# Low latency in PureData(Pd) with Jack in Ubuntu Studio 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, ubuntu-studio

I´m having trouble to make PureData(Pd) to work at low latency in Ubuntu Studio 12.04.

I get Pd and Jack to work together with my Audio Interface (Alesis IO4) but only at a frames/Period of 1024, which means a latency of 45.2 ms.

As soon as I try to lower the Frames/period to lower the latency, I get an Audio I/O error from Pd.

I tried to mess around with the oder parameters, but the only one who appears to affect Pd (and the latency) is the Frames/Period.

I also tried to use the configuration explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToJACKConfiguration , but it doesn´t work either.
I really need to get the lowest latency possible, because I work with live instruments and proccesing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Jack is probably your best option here. Ubuntu Studio is already prepared for low latency, with linux-lowlatency preinstalled, as well as realtime privileges being set up.

Use qjackctl to control jack. Read more about that here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ProAudioIntro#UbuntuStudio.2BAC8-ProAudioIntro.2BAC8-1204.Starting_Jack

Then, start pd from the command line, with:

```
 pd -rt -jack -alsamidi -audiobuf 10
```

If you have more questions, don't hesitate to get in touch with Ubuntu Studio users and devs. Find contact info here https://ubuntustudio.org/support/. We have a mail list, forum section, irc channels, google+ community, etc.

For puredata specific issues, there is a mail list, forum and also a IRC channel. Check out the puredata home page for more info on that.

I myself am often available on the IRC channel #ubuntustudio at irc.freenode.net

(I'm project lead of Ubuntu Studio and maintainer of linux-lowlatency)